# hibernate query with join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tax")
public class TaxReturn {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "period")
    private String fillingPeriod;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
    @Column(name = "total_tax")
    private int totalTax;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tax_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "emp")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "other_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "tax_amount")
    private int taxAmount;
}
```

The information above represent a return which consist a list of employees saying how much tax has been paid. The return entity contains the total amount of all employees. I need to write a query in HQL which will retrieve an employee using the return id and employee id. Below is what I have written but I am getting an error since it is not generating the right mysql.

```
session.getTransaction().begin();
Long taxReturnId = 5L;
Long empId = 4L;
Query query = session.createQuery("select p.employees from TaxReturn p left join Employee e where p.id = '5' and e.id = '4'");
List<Employee> employeeList = query.list();
System.out.println(employeeList.get(0).toString());
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Is it the right query to write?

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: I find the relationship little hazy. Can multiple employees have one `TaxReturn` ??

Comment: Looks like you want to retrieve  `Employee` #4 along with _no `TaxReturn` info at all_. So,   `FROM Employee e WHERE  e.id = 4`

Comment: Could you state the business you want to solve with the query in simple sentence (without technical things)

Comment: Since it is an employer that is submitted the tax return for his employees, so yes multiple employees can belong in one tax return. But i don't want to make this relationship bidirectional.

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I need to be able to retrieve an employee for a particular return

Comment: `select emp from Employee emp INNER JOIN TaxReturn ret where ret.id = '4' and emp.id = '5'`  should work. try this

Comment: @ShafinMahmud nope does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be:

```
select p.employees from TaxReturn p left join p.employees e where p.id = '5' and e.id = '4'
```

N.B. the join part is different from yours as you have to specify the field mapping the relation when joining.

Also you could just return a `TaxReturn` and from there getting the `List` of `Employee`:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select p from TaxReturn p left join p.employees e where p.id = '5' and e.id = '4'");
List<Employee> employeeList = query.singleResult().getEmployees();
```

Also i notice that you mapped the relationship in an unconventional way as 
normally unidirectional mapping is done on the `ManyToOne` side and not the opposite. There are also some performance related problem with that, check out this [Article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for more details